# Staging selecting ranges without creating new file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When I open VScode as a difftool with the `git difftool` command it works as expected. However when I stage selected ranges in my staging area appears a new file instead of a modification of the edited file. This behaviour does not occur when I start the VS code and navigate to the directory manually. I think it is probably something with the git configuration. Any ideas?

These are the lines from my git configuraiton:

```
diff.tool=default-difftool
difftool.default-difftool.cmd=code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
merge.tool=vscode
mergetool.vscode.cmd=code --wait $MERGED
```

Comment: Can you give an example of `git difftool` invocation which leads you to this "a new file is created" situation ?

Comment: I have a repository named e.g. Core with the file file.txt in the subdirectory UI. I open bash in repository root folder via the terminal. I edit the file UI/file.txt which gives my unstaged changes. I run the difftool command. 

(User@ASDRN01-XXX MSYS ~/Work/Workspace/Core (master) git difftool).

VS opens up and I add some of the changes to the staging area with the "Stage Selected Ranges" option. 

When I then invoke git status I have new file asdf.txt in the staging area instead of the modified file UI/asdf.txt (this file remains untouched).

Comment: That seems likely to be a bug in VS: that it told Git to create a new file named `asdf.txt`, rather than to update the existing index copy of the existing file named `UI/asdf.txt`. (Remember that to Git, files just have names with embedded slashes in them. There are no such things as folders, those are figments of your OS's imagination. :-) So files are named `foo/bar` and a file named `bar` is just a file named `bar`, you have to name it `foo/bar` if you want your *OS* to see it in a folder. This holds for all index copies of all files.)

Comment: You can probably avoid such a VS bug—I don't know; I avoid everything Microsoft so that I don't *have* to avoid their bugs—by not working within any subdirectory of the top level of your repository. That is, never allow VS itself to start up in a subdirectory, so that VS has to name each file with a full(er) path.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll also report this issue to their github as bug. I thought that I was just not using the VS correctly. Thanks.